# MATLAB function to return 8 bits of a decimal number

Tags: matlab, function, bitwise-operators

I am trying to write some MATLAB code to return the 8 bits of a decimal number that I provide as an input. The 8 bits that are returned will be used later in a Simulink model. What is the best way to accomplish this? Here is what I've tried.

```
gcf = 123;

bitwise_gcf = dec2bin(gcf,8);

gcf_bit1 = bitwise_gcf(0);
gcf_bit2 = bitwise_gcf(1);
gcf_bit3 = bitwise_gcf(2);
gcf_bit4 = bitwise_gcf(3);
gcf_bit5 = bitwise_gcf(4);
gcf_bit6 = bitwise_gcf(5);
gcf_bit7 = bitwise_gcf(6);
gcf_bit8 = bitwise_gcf(7);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`bitget`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html).  `bitget` takes in a number, matrix, vector, etc. and the bit positions of what you want to extract from each number in the input.  Optionally, you can specify an assumed data type.   In your case, this isn't optional.  Make sure you specify `uint8` as the datatype, as I'm assuming you want **unsigned** 8-bit integers.

For our specific case, you want the input to be a single number, and the bit positions to be specified by a vector going from 1 to 8, as you want all of the bits for an `uint8` number.  The output will be an array of bits where each position in this array gives you the bit extracted from the input number.

```
>> gcf = 123;
>> gcf_bits = bitget(gcf, 1:8, 'uint8')

gcf_bits =

     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0
```

`gcf_bits` will be an 8 element array where each element gives you the i<sup>th</sup> bit, starting from 1 - the least significant bit to 8 - the most significant bit.

If you want the reverse order, simply reverse the ordering of the second input:

```
>> gcf = 123;
>> gcf_bits = bitget(gcf, 8:-1:1, 'uint8')

gcf_bits =

     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
```

Comment: However, I just noticed that the bits are the reverse of the actual binary number, but this isn't a problem. :)

Comment: @ShankarKumar - Yes :) Just do `bitget(gcf, 8:-1:1, 'uint8');`.  `1:8` gets the LSB to MSB.  If you want the opposite order, you need to specify the input bit position vector to be the reverse.

Comment: @ShankarKumar - I've made an edit to ensure that both cases are respected.

Comment: Also `dec2bin(gcf,8)-'0'` or `de2bi(gcf,8)` would work

Comment: @LuisMendo - yes that could work! :D `de2bi` is part of the Comm. toolbox so I try and stay away from it.